# Ambient occlusion not appearing

Tags: ambient-occlusion

I cant use ambient occlusion, the checkbox is just not there .

Render engine is Cycles

[image]

Comment: It looks like it has been replaced by the Fast GI Approximation option in the Render Panel > Light Paths but I don't know how it works. Or use an Input > AO node in the object material but you'll need to create it in each object of your scene

Answer (score 0):

Cycles is a path tracer. Which means it calculates physically accurate shadows. Eevee uses ambient occlusion as a form of mimicking shadows, which is not physically accurate.
If you want more control on shadows, you can render out shadow layer as a separate pass in cycles.